# Координаты мыши на экране в режиме реального времени

Tags: c#

Форма, размерами скажем 200х200, поверх всех окон.
Координаты мыши на экране получаем:

```
int CursorX = Cursor.Position.X;
int CursorY = Cursor.Position.Y;
label1.Text = CursorX.ToString() + " x " + CursorY.ToString();
```

Нужно чтобы этот label всегда показывал координаты мыши, даже если она не на форме, MouseMove - не катит, только когда мышка на форме..

Answer (score 2):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6362/Global-System-Hooks-in-NET посмотрите данную статью

Comment: @beliy26rus, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение. Лучше скопировать честь информации в ответ так как статью могут удалить или перенести.